# Poisson distribution

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions

Consider this problem:

The number of telephone calls made to an exchange is Poisson distributed with a mean of 6 
calls per hour. Find the probability that a call will be made within 10 minutes given that no call was made in the past 15 minutes.

---

My question:

I know the 15 minutes interval mentioned does not have any effect since the Poisson distribution has a lack of memory property.
And I know the answer is the probability that the interval does not exceed 10 minutes : $1 - e^{-6\frac{10}{60}}$.

But  can't we also say that the answer is the probability that exactly 1 call was made within an interval of 10 minutes: 
$P(1 call) = e^{-1} . 1^1 / 1!   = e^{-1}  $    ?

And if not, then how can get the probability that exactly 3 calls (for instance) are made within the next 10 minutes, given that no calls were made within the past 15 minutes ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us call $X$ the number of calls in the next $10$ minutes. You say that by the lack of memory property, then this does not depend on what has happened in the past $15$ minutes, and this is correct.

Additionally, the distribution of $X$ is well known:
$$
X\sim\mathrm{Poiss}(1).
$$
Specifically, 
$$
P(X=k)=\frac{1^k}{k!}e^{-1}=\frac{1}{k!}e^{-1},
$$
for every $k\in\mathbb N$. Hence, you are correct in saying that the probability that there is at least a call is
$$
P(X\ge1)=1-P(X=0)=1-e^{-1}.
$$
Note that this is the probability that there is **at least** one call, and not **exactly** one call. This is why you do not get the same result as computing $P(X=1)$. To get the probability that $3$ calls are made, 
$$
P(X=3)=\frac16e^{-1}.
$$
It may also be helpful to note that
$$
P(X\ge1)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X=k)=P(X=1)+P(X=2)+P(X=3)+\dots.
$$

Comment: Please replace $\mathrm{Poiss}(e^{-1})$ by $\mathrm{Poiss}(1)$.

Comment: @Did, I find it impressive how closely you read every post. Thank you, I have edited the post.